# What is Mikrobus purpose?

Tags: embedded, pinout, mplab, board

I'm new to embedded systems. I have [MPLAB Xpress Evaluation Board](https://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails/DM164140).

I see that the board has MikroBUS connectors. Going through the internet, I couldn't understand what is the purpose of the MikroBUS? Which functionality does it allow? What is the way to connect to it?

Comment: It's just a standard connection system so that you can plug multiple different types of modules into the same socket. I haven't seen any use of it outside of a learning/prototyping environment.

Comment: Can you please expand - what should be connected to it or how to use it?

Comment: You use it like any other GPIO, you can connect [hundreds of different modules](https://www.mikroe.com/click) to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification is [here](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/standards/mikrobus/mikrobus-standard-specification-v200.pdf). It simply provides a standard set of interfaces that make it easy to plug together various kinds of evaluation modules in order to prototype a system.

Comment: So basically its goal is only to connect my board to other boards? And as a beginner, I shouldn't really care about it, right?

Comment: Yes to the first question. I don't understand the second question, since I have no idea what it is you're beginning. Would your project benefit from using any of the available Mikrobus modules?